# Replace a variable every where in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I need to write a shell script such that I have to read .sh script and find a particular variable (for example, Variable_Name="variable1") and take out is value(variable1).
In other shell script if Variable_Name is used I need to replace it with its Value(variable1)

Comment: Variables are often used more than once. Hence the name - they are variable. Names may repeat in different scopes without being related. So which value will you use? Can you execute the source script without unwanted side effects, to evaluate the variables value in the end?

Comment: In this case I have only one variable in the complete source file with that name and one corresponding value.

Comment: Programmatically modifying your programs is almost always the wrong solution. Change the program so that it accepts a parameter you can specify at run time instead.

Comment: What do you mean by "used"?  In a shell script, if you write `echo '$foo'`, the string `$foo` is not interpolated, so the variable `foo` is *not* being "used".  Should it be replaced in that instance?  The question is ambiguous and unclear.  If you can provide more precision, your answer will probably become clear.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach, to build on, might be:

```
assignment=$(echo 'Variable_Name="variable1"' | sed -r 's/Variable_Name=(.*)/\1/')
echo $assignment 
"variable1"
```

Depending on variable type, the value might be quoted or not, quoted with single apostrophs or quotes. That might be neccessary (String with or without blanks) or superflous. Behind the assignment there might be furter code:

```
pi=3.14;v=42;
```

or a comment:

```
user=janis  # Janis Joplin
```

it might be complicated:

```
expr="foobar; O'Reilly " # trailing blank important
```

But only you may know, how complicated it might get. Maybe the simple case is already sufficient. If the new script looks similar, it might work, or not:

```
targetV=INSERT_HERE; secondV=23
# oops: secondV accidnetally hidden: 
targetV="foobar; O'Reilly " # trailing blank important; secondV=23
```

If the second script is under your control, you can prevent such problems easily. If source and target language are identical, what worked here should work there too.